# How to can I multiple column same id group by ? - Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

My database as below:

```
id |group_id |property_id |type     |
1  |   9     |     13     |property |
2  |   9     |     14     |property |
3  |   9     |     15     |property | 
4  |   9     |     14     |variant  |
5  |   8     |     14     |property |
6  |   8     |     15     |variant  |
7  |   8     |     13     |property |
```

My code as below:

```
 $stock_get_property = StockPropertyTemplate::groupBy('group_id')->selectRaw('count(type) as quantity , group_id')->where('type' , 'property')->get();
        $stock_get_variant = StockPropertyTemplate::groupBy('group_id')->selectRaw('count(type) as quantity , group_id')->where('type' , 'variant')->get();
```

I want the total grouping them. groupBy('group_id') by type="property" and "variant". How can I combine two queries?

the array output I want to create as below;

```
id |group_id |count_property|count_variant|
1  |   9     |       3      |     1       |
2  |   8     |       2      |     1       |
```

How can I do it with Laravel? Please help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved by single query:

```
SELECT
    group_id,
    COUNT(NULLIF(type, 'variant')) as count_property,
    COUNT(NULLIF(type, 'property')) as count_variant
FROM StockPropertyTemplate
GROUP BY group_id;
```

or in Laravel style:

```
$stock_get_property_and_variant = 
    StockPropertyTemplate::groupBy('group_id')
        ->selectRaw(
            "group_id,
             COUNT(NULLIF(type, 'variant')) as count_property,
             COUNT(NULLIF(type, 'property')) as count_variant"
        )
        ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
        ->get();
```

[SQL live code here](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=3a3958572ee1e23e8d683e5a2dae3041&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Answer (score 1):

My solution as below;

```
    $stock_get_property = StockPropertyTemplate::groupBy('group_id')->selectRaw('count(type) as total_property , group_id ')->where('type' , 'property')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    $stock_get_variant = StockPropertyTemplate::groupBy('group_id')->selectRaw('count(type) as total_variant , group_id')->where('type' , 'variant')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();

   //assigning $variant array -> total_variant
   $variant = [];
   foreach ($stock_get_variant as  $row) {
       $variant[] = $row->total_variant;
   }

   //array push made
   $i = 0;
   $all_values = [];
   foreach ($stock_get_property as $row) {
       $all_values[] = array('group_id' => $row->group_id , 'total_property' => $row->total_property , 'total_variant' => $variant[$i]);
       $i++;
   }
```

This code is taking care of my work.